# Detect Grub target currently in use

Tags: grub

I would like to know what `--target` parameter was grub installed with.

If I re-install Grub (booting from rescue disk and *chroot*ing to original root) it will choose a target platform automatically, based on the way the current environment was booted. Meaning:

- Debian installer (in rescue mode) has UEFI, and if I boot it in UEFI mode it will install UEFI loader.
- Ubuntu live CD does not have an UEFI loader, it will be booted in standard BIOS mode, and it will try to install an MBR-based loader.

I am trying to *restore* my system in the way it was. What config file can I parse to get the right value for `--target` without any guesswork?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a directory under `/boot/grub` (besides *fonts* and *locale*). The name of this directory matches the platform in use.

This directory contains mostly files with `.mod` extension and a few with `.lst`.

The same directory (contents may differ slightly) exists in grub's lib path (on Debian this is `/usr/lib/grub`).